# How to set HTML image to default location view

Tags: javascript, css, image, cordova, position

I created a phonegap application for ios and android. It is an image viewer for floor plans that scrolls from the left to the right.

[image: default position location]

my code

`<div id="imageContainer"><img id="floorPlan"   src="images/s/f/a.png"/></div>`

a use iscroll.

I can scroll from the left to right and vice versa. When I open the app/page, the default location is on the left, but I want to be able to set the default location to right using javascript, css, or anything else.

[image: set to position location right]

Comment: We need to see more code. Please provide the relevant CSS and javascript as well

Comment: Yes, please show us what you have done so far.  We currently do not have enough information to help you in really any way.

Comment: my app link http://www.emannthod.0fees.net/i/ open it on IOS devices or android.